# Identifying Plot Name or Visualization Implementation

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'm working on a dataset of SMS records [datetime_entry, sms_sent] and I was looking to copy a really effective trend visual from a well cited Electricity demand study. Does anyone know the name of this plot, or the implementation of something similar in Python (as I'm not sure this was done in Python).

I know how to subplot the 4 charts after splitting the data by quarter, I'm just stumped on the plot type and stylization.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might need to re-read it, its pretty obvious what im after, and someone below answered immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `matplotlib` calls an [eventplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot.html).

Essentially each vertical line represents an occurance of a Mwh demand during that specific hour. So each row in the plot should have as many vertical lines as there are days in that quarter.

While it works in this plot for these data, relying on the combination of alpha level + data density can be slightly unreliable as the data change as the number of overlapping points is not readily visible. So you can also create a similar visualization using [hist2d](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/hist2d.html), where you manually specify your bins.

Comment: Thanks for this! Really appreciate the links. I think you're right about the confusion between data density and alpha level, but the way you described the event plot sounds like I could input this data at a user+date level. 

If that is the case, a dark area would mean either lots of traffic AND/OR lots of customers using the platform. 

Both scenarios have impacts on our system, this might be a good way to comb for both at once, then dive into the dark patches to identify the cause.

Comment: Definitely agree with you there- dark patches = more users. The main thing that a 2d histogram gives you is a more direct mapping to how many occurences are present in those dark patches. But for a first pass, and when you know there's ~90 occruences per row (since it's by day by quarter) I think the `eventplot` should good enough :)

Comment: I could do 90 occurances per row and it would eliminate the issue completely right?

Comment: It would dillute the issue (as seen in the original plot here), but if in reality you have more than 90 occurences and you're only visualizing a smaller sample you'll be missing data. Though if you sample is representative, I don't see too much of an issue.